# Match value in array, that is inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects that looks like this:

```
0:
depth:0
id:37
index:0
label:"user"
name:"r"
next:(3) [265, 355, 387]
```

I want to match an id with the values inside `next: Array(3)`

```
findNext = function(idToMatch) {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        if (nodes.next[i] === idToMatch) { return nodes[i].id }
    }
};
```

`idToMatch` is one integer, just like `id:37` in above example.

`const nodes = this.state.nodes;` is the array that contains objects as the one above.

How can I check if `this.state.nodes[i].next` contains the `idToMatch` and, if so, return `this.state.nodes[i].id`?

Comment: Can you give a fuller description of the `nodes`? JSON format, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with using ES2016's [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes);

```
findNext = function(idToMatch) {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;
    let matches = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].next.includes(idToMatch)) matches.push(nodes[i].id);
    }

    return matches;
};
```

If not:

```
findNext = function(idToMatch) {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;
    let matches = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        if (nodes[i].next.indexOf(idToMatch) > -1) matches.push(nodes[i].id);
    }

    return matches;
};
```

Comment: This works thanks! but if a node is connected to multiple other nodes, it doesn't return all the values. Would this be a good way to adjust the code? `if (nodes[i].next.includes(idToMatch)) { arr.push(nodes[i].id) }` and declare `let arr = [];` on top?

Comment: Right, if there is the possibility for multiple nodes to match that is the correct way. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the matched object and then get any property of the object you want

```
this.state.nodes[i].next.find(o=> o === idToMatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another for loop inside the loop? like this:

```
const findNext = function(idToMatch) {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        for(let node in nodes.next){
           if(node.id == idToMatch){
             return node;
           } 
        }
        if (nodes.next[i] === idToMatch) { return nodes[i].id }
    }
};
```